# Exception in Application constructor, JavaFX

Tags: javafx

first of all, I'm a complete begginer in Java and JavaFX, using IntelliJ Idea for that.
I have tried to download and run a piece of game's code but ran into a problem that I can't pinpoint the cause of.

I have this in my VM options:

```
--module-path 
${PATH_TO_FX};${OUTPUT} 
--add-modules 
javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Error message itself:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class gg.game.Game
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:891)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1142)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:705)
    at gg.game/gg.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:19)
    ... 14 more
Exception running application gg.game.Game
```

Game's code:

```
package gg.game;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Game extends Application {
    public static ArrayList<Block> platforms = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<KeyCode,Boolean> keys = new HashMap<>(); 

    Image backgroundImg = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("background.png"));
    public static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 45;
    public static final int MARIO_SIZE = 40;

    public static Pane appRoot = new Pane();
    public static Pane gameRoot = new Pane();

    public Character player;
    int levelNumber = 0;
    private int levelWidth;

    private void initContent(){
        ImageView backgroundIV = new ImageView(backgroundImg);
        backgroundIV.setFitHeight(14*BLOCK_SIZE);
        backgroundIV.setFitWidth(212*BLOCK_SIZE);

        levelWidth = LevelData.levels[levelNumber][0].length()*BLOCK_SIZE;
        for(int i = 0; i < LevelData.levels[levelNumber].length; i++){
            String line = LevelData.levels[levelNumber][i];
            for(int j = 0; j < line.length();j++){
                switch (line.charAt(j)){
                    case '0':
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        Block platformFloor = new Block(Block.BlockType.PLATFORM, j * BLOCK_SIZE, i * BLOCK_SIZE);
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        Block brick = new Block(Block.BlockType.BRICK,j*BLOCK_SIZE,i*BLOCK_SIZE);
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        Block bonus = new Block(Block.BlockType.BONUS,j*BLOCK_SIZE,i*BLOCK_SIZE);
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        Block stone = new Block(Block.BlockType.STONE,j * BLOCK_SIZE, i * BLOCK_SIZE);
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        Block PipeTopBlock = new Block(Block.BlockType.PIPE_TOP,j * BLOCK_SIZE, i * BLOCK_SIZE);
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        Block PipeBottomBlock = new Block(Block.BlockType.PIPE_BOTTOM,j * BLOCK_SIZE, i * BLOCK_SIZE);
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        Block InvisibleBlock = new Block(Block.BlockType.INVISIBLE_BLOCK,j * BLOCK_SIZE, i * BLOCK_SIZE);
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        player =new Character();
        player.setTranslateX(0);
        player.setTranslateY(400);
        player.translateXProperty().addListener((obs,old,newValue)->{
            int offset = newValue.intValue();
            if(offset>640 && offset<levelWidth-640){
                gameRoot.setLayoutX(-(offset-640));
                backgroundIV.setLayoutX(-(offset-640));
            }
        });
        gameRoot.getChildren().add(player);
        appRoot.getChildren().addAll(backgroundIV,gameRoot);
    }

    private void update(){
        if(isPressed(KeyCode.UP) && player.getTranslateY()>=5){
            player.jumpPlayer();
        }
        if(isPressed(KeyCode.LEFT) && player.getTranslateX()>=5){
            player.setScaleX(-1);
            player.animation.play();
            player.moveX(-5);
        }
        if(isPressed(KeyCode.RIGHT) && player.getTranslateX()+40 <=levelWidth-5){
            player.setScaleX(1);
            player.animation.play();
            player.moveX(5);
        }
        if(player.playerVelocity.getY()<10){ 
           player.playerVelocity = player.playerVelocity.add(0,1);
        }
        player.moveY((int)player.playerVelocity.getY());
    }
    private boolean isPressed(KeyCode key){
        return keys.getOrDefault(key,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        initContent();
        Scene scene = new Scene(appRoot,1200,620);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event-> keys.put(event.getCode(), true));
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            keys.put(event.getCode(), false);
             player.animation.stop();
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Mini Mario");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                update();
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I would be grateful to any kind of response. Thank you.

Comment: You're calling "new Image(xxx);" and xxx is not an inputstream. You should show Game.java especially line 19. I'm guessing your using getResourceAsStream and the path is wrong so it is returning null?

Comment: Thank you, I will check that. Also added game's code.

Comment: Great, this line here "getClass().getResourceAsStream("background.png")" is probably returning null. When you run your application, background.png needs to be in a folder on your classpath. In this case it needs be in the same folder as your Game.class is.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, that worked perfectly!